# How to use recursion to choose a number in an array within a larger array

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function where I have a 2d array with a bunch of integer pairs, like `array = [[2,3],[4,7],[6,1],[8,2]]` and it goes through the array, selecting the higher value in each pair, and putting those into pairs, and doing that again and again, alternating between choosing the higher and lower value until one integer results.
so for example,

```
array = [[1,2],[3,4]] choose maximums from each pair
[2,4] pair the maximums up
[2] choose minimum
```

Here's the code I have so far.

```
array = [[1,2],[3,4]]
def choose(twoarray):
 if twoarray[1] > twoarray [2]:
   return twoarray[1]
 else:
   return twoarray[2] 

def combineArray(a):
  outputArray = []
  if not a:
    return 0
  return outputArray.append(choose(a[0])+combineArray(a[1:]))

print(combineArray(array))
```

Comment: Also, sorry that this is a basic question. I'm new to recursion and I couldn't find something exactly like this.

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays. There are no arrays in core Python.

Comment: @VintiumDust can you include a couple questions after your code? It helps if we know what you're trying to learn.

Comment: Is the 2d array length a power of 2?

Comment: Does it matter what it starts with? Does it have to pick the higher value first?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether it's important that, at the lowest depth, the **maximum** of the list is taken, this can be done in the following ways:

If it doesn't matter what to do at the lowest depth, just so long as it alternates:

```
def min_max(x, mx=1):
    try:
        x[0][0]
    except TypeError:
        if mx == 1:
            return max(x)
        else:
            return min(x)
    if mx == 1:
        return max([min_max(i, 0) for i in x])
    else:
        return min([min_max(i, 1) for i in x])
```

If it does matter, here's one way of doing it:

```
def depth(l):
    depths = []
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            depths.append(depth(item))
    if len(depths) > 0:
        return 1 + max(depths)
    return 1

def min_max(x, mx=None):
    if mx == None:
        mx = depth(x) % 2
    try:
        x[0][0]
    except TypeError:
        return max(x)
    if mx == 1:
        return max([min_max(i, 0) for i in x])
    else:
        return min([min_max(i, 1) for i in x])
```

Both of these can be run by simply doing:

```
min_max([[2,3],[4,7],[6,1],[8,2]])
```

Also, just so you know, I would avoid using lists in recursive functions. Python handles mutables a bit different then to how you would expect, and it's **very** easy to get confused.

That being said, some recursive functions actually rely on the way python handles mutables, such as some depth first search functions, so if you know how to use it don't hesitate.